# Why Did Filatov Use an OR Statement?

Tags: javascript, throttling, iife

I've branched Dmitry Filatov's jQuery-Plugins (https://github.com/dfilatov/jquery-plugins) in an effort to learn how this @#^#$% wizard of a man wrote his throttle and debounce wrappers.

Of all the things that make absolutely no sense to me, his throttle wraps the setTimeout() in an IIFE as part of an OR statement:

```
// why the extra complexity here?
timer || (function() {
   if (needInvoke) {
     fn.apply(ctx, args);
     needInvoke = false;
     timer = setTimeout(arguments.callee, timeout);
   } else {
     timer = null;
   }
})();
```

As far as I can tell, it just prevents the IIFE from executing if the timer has a value. Is it a matter of performance?

Comment: It's to prevent more than one timer from running. Also, that code is seriously old; `arguments.callee` should never be used in modern code.

Comment: Note the warning at the top of the repository readme.

Comment: There's nothing terribly "wizardy" here, though it may seem magical if you're not familiar with JavaScript conventions like this. Honestly a lot of this is just syntax junk imposed by limitations in earlier (e.g. pre ES5) versions of JavaScript. Don't be dazzled by stuff like that.

Comment: It's a shortcut for `if (!timer) { if (needInvoke) ... else ... }`

Comment: i agree with tadman as it's instead of making the outter check  if (!inThrottle) {....}

Comment: @Pointy yeah, project was last updated 7 years ago. Last serious updates were 8 years ago. That's about the last time people could use `argument.callee` without a serious scolding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of short-circuiting, logical operators can be used as substitutes for `if`.

```
expr1 || expr2
```

is equivalent to

```
if (!expr1) expr2
```

But since the arguments to `||` have to be expressions, you can't put statement blocks there. An IIFE can be used to wrap a block of statements in an expression.

If you undo those transformations, you get the more straightforward code:

```
if (!timer) {
  if (needInvoke) {
    fn.apply(ctx, args);
    needInvoke = false;
    timer = setTimeout(arguments.callee, timeout);
  } else {
    timer = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that needs this, I found a tutorial that makes the deprecated callee moot: https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/javascript-throttle-and-debounce-patterns/

I still think Filatov is a !#$%@$ wizard.